# Dynamically change a var of value of an input field and / or radio buttons

Tags: jquery, forms, input

Quick question, cant seem to figure this out myself.

I have a form with some radio buttons grouped together (choose amount from list), and an input field (specify your amount).

When the user chooses one of the radio buttons or the input field, i want a var out of it.

I got the radio buttons working great, the input howeover will not change on key up. But Why?

Also, i think this could be coded much smarter, any suggestions? Thanks!

```
<form method="post" class="formDoneer" name="formDoneer">

  <fieldset id="doneerField">
<legend>Ik doneer</legend>
<div class="radioBedrag">
      <input id="5" name="bedrag" value="5" type="radio" required>
      <label for="5">5</label>

      <input id="10" name="bedrag" value="10" type="radio" required>
      <label for="10">10</label>

      <input id="25" name="bedrag" value="25" type="radio" required>
      <label for="25">25</label>

      <input id="50" name="bedrag" value="50" type="radio" required>
      <label for="50">50</label>

      <input id="100" name="bedrag" value="100" type="radio" required>
      <label for="100">100</label>

      <input id="250" name="bedrag" value="250" type="radio" required>
      <label for="250">250</label>

      <label for="anders">Anders
    <input id="anders" name="bedragAnders" type="text" placeholder="anders" >
  </label>


    </div>
<div class="radioFrequentie">
      <input id="maand" name="frequentie" value="maand" type="radio" required>
      <label for="maand">Per maand</label>
      <input id="kwartaal" name="frequentie" value="kwartaal" type="radio" required>
      <label for="kwartaal">Per kwartaal</label>
      <input id="jaar" name="frequentie" value="jaar" type="radio" required>
      <label for="jaar">Per jaar</label>
      <input id="eenmalig" name="frequentie" value="eenmalig" type="radio" required>
      <label for="eenmalig">Eenmalig</label>
    </div>

  <fieldset>
<div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Bevestigen" class="cta" id="submitForm">
    </div>
```

this is my jQuery so far:

```
$('.radioBedrag input, .radioFrequentie input').click(function() {

      valueBedrag = $('.radioBedrag input:checked').val();
      valueFrequentie = $('.radioFrequentie input:checked').val();

      if($('input[name=bedragAnders]').is(':focus')) {
          valueBedrag = $('input[name=bedragAnders]').val();

     } 

     $('input[name=bedragAnders]').keyup(function(){
          valueBedrag = $('input[name=bedragAnders]').val(); 
     });

    $('label[for=accept]').text("Ik geef toestemming om per " + valueFrequentie + " €" + valueBedrag + " van mijn rekening af te schrijven.");  


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the radio buttons you can use the `click()` event, but for a text field you'll need another event like `keyup()`:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(checkValues);
$('input[type=text]').keyup(checkValues);

function checkValues () {

    valueBedrag = $('.radioBedrag input:checked').val();
    valueFrequentie = $('.radioFrequentie input:checked').val();

    if ($('input[name=bedragAnders]').val() != '') {
        valueBedrag = $('input[name=bedragAnders]').val();
    }

    $('label[for=accept]').text("Ik geef toestemming om per " + valueFrequentie + " €" + valueBedrag + " van mijn rekening af te schrijven.");

}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xf6659u/2/)

But you will need to add additional logic. For instance, you should be able to enter either a value at 'Anders' OR click a radio button, not both.
I've made a [**basic example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xf6659u/3/) containing such logic